# sql server insert query working on local but not on hosting server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

when I use the following code to insert into a table it works fine on my local testing/development server, but when I upload it to the webhosting server it doesn't work, and won't throw an error or exception either.

```
public void insertEnq(List<string> valuesparam)
{
    SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection([//connection string details]);

    //Create Command object
    SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

    try
    {
        // Open Connection
        thisConnection.Open();

        // Create INSERT statement with named parameters
        nonqueryCommand.CommandText = "Insert Into [project].[dbo].[LP_Records]("
        + "f_name, "
        + "l_name, "
        + "email, "
        + "country, "
        + "country_code, "
        + "phone_no, "
        + "interested_in, "
        + "area, "
        + "comments, "
        + "page_url, "
        + "page_refferal)"
        + " Values "
        +"(@F_Name, "
        + "@L_Name, "
        + "@Email, "
        + "@Country, "
        + "@Country_Code, "
        + "@Phone_No, "
        + "@Interested_In, "
        + "@Area, "
        + "@Comments, "
        + "@Page_URL, "
        + "@Page)";

        // Add Parameters to Command Parameters collection
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@F_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@L_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Country_Code", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone_No", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Interested_In", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Comments", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Page_URL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@Page", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);


        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@F_Name"].Value = valuesparam[1];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@L_Name"].Value = valuesparam[2];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Email"].Value = valuesparam[3];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Country"].Value = valuesparam[7];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Country_Code"].Value = valuesparam[8];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Phone_No"].Value = valuesparam[10];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Interested_In"].Value = valuesparam[5];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Area"].Value = valuesparam[6];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Comments"].Value = Request["txtEnquiry"];
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Page_URL"].Value 
          = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters["@Page"].Value = valuesparam[0];


        nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Check your connection string, the string you need might differ from the production server and the local server.

Comment: Post the error you are getting. Could be permissions, port settings, firewall, etc. Sounds like you don't have the server configured to work across the network.

Comment: That's because you're intentionally ignoring the error. Where's your catch?

Comment: I tried the try catch, but of no use

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and what "no use" means?

Comment: it means it gives no errors and and in the catch section I just printed the error message, and no error is displayed on on the local server and on the web-hosting server it also gives no error, just a plain white sheet, while on the local it do insert the data into the database but not when i run it on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Firstly is the webserver on a local machine? If so then there is no network problems that can occure but as stated by JeremyK it could very well be the permissions. Find out if your webhosting server's database needs a username and password (Most cases it is) and then just edit your connection string to the database.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I'll remove my comment. Should have scrolled all the way over (I ***hate*** horizontal scrollbars on this site).

Comment: the connection string is just fine, its working on other pages